# Can't extract xml to sql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, csv

New to xml->mysql extract, and I have an xml file trying to map out to a mysql table. xml file fields are different from my phpmyadmin table fields so I need to map them (**can't change the fields or recreate tables**) like below;
test.xml;

```
<persons>
<person>
<name>Al</name>
<hobby>Golf</hobby>
<description>been doing this for years</description>
<age>45</age>
<latitude>42.7303</latitude>
<longitude>85.7741<longitude>
</person>
</persons>
```

tbTest fields are; id, player, experience, age, latitude, longitude, etc........
When I run this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "test.xml" INTO TABLE tbTest()
```

Instead of one row, I get 16 rows with bits and pieces in each row and one of them has the full description, which is really all I need. But it should only be one row, right?

Then when I run this instead

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "test.xml" INTO TABLE listing ROWS IDENTIFIED BY ,    '<description>';
```

I get the one row I want but no data whatsoever.

I've also tried

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'test.xml' INTO TABLE 
tbTest(description,Longitude,Longitude) 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<persons>';
```

Then I tried to add fields to tbTest(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (id='col3', player='col2'....) and no luck with that at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `person` element node represents a row. Its children element nodes represent the columns.

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'test.xml' 
INTO TABLE tbTest
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY 'person';
```

Comment: Exactly, so my question is why the columns are resulted as rows? Because <name>Al</name> is the first row in my table results, 
<hobby>Golf</hobby> is the second row, the third row shows a weird int; 10, 
<description>been doing this for years</description> is the fourth row and so on and so forth. So it sounds like it's resulting backwards; rows instead of columns. So I would be happen if I could get one row with the description in it. Not 16 rows

Comment: Please compare my example with your source again, you did not define the `person` element and but some invalid/unknown element names (with `<` and `>`).

Comment: Thanks for your help and pointing out my typo. But I think this is a headache table and doesn't like to take any data and when I correct the statement it creates an empty row. The only statement that has sort of worked is; LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.xml' 
INTO TABLE tbTest(description); It extracts all the descriptions. But it also creates a ton of empty rows. if I could extract other data such as Golf, then it'd be worth deleting the empty rows. So that's where I am and thanks again for your help.